# babel transpiled code use absolute imports

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Transpiling code using `@babel/cli` with the following command:

```
babel --plugins @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions www/js/origin.js --out-file www/js/result.js
```

produces a file which require imports using absolute path from my computer. Of course, running that on the server breaks as path is not found.

Here is an example of absolute imports:

```
import _slicedToArray from "/Users/myself/project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/es6/slicedToArray";
import _createClass from "/Users/myself/project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/es6/createClass";
import _inherits from "/Users/myself/project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/es6/inherits";
import _possibleConstructorReturn from "/Users/myself/project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/es6/possibleConstructorReturn";
import _getPrototypeOf from "/Users/myself/project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/es6/getPrototypeOf";
import _classCallCheck from "/Users/myself/project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/es6/classCallCheck";
import _typeof from "/Users/myself/project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/es6/typeof";
```

Is there any way for the transpiled file to include everything it needs inline?

I don't use any specific `babel.config.js` or `babelrc` file at the moment.

Comment: You must have a babelrc somewhere, whether it's a `.babelrc` file, `.babelrc.js` file, or `package.json#babel` field, because those imports are something you have to opt into with the `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` module. It could be in some parent folder.

Comment: using --no-babelrc produces the same. We tried to delete the babel.config.js which uses the @vue/app preset but it doesn't change that.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. Would you be able to make a reproducible example? There's definitely some other plugins loading from somewhere.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: no. Didn't find a way out of this

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7183#issuecomment-509975452), the react-app preset has an option called `absoluteRuntime` which is set to `true` by default. So, try setting it as `false` as shown below.

```
 "presets": [
["react-app", { "absoluteRuntime": false }],]
```

The original answer was given by [VasiliKubarka](https://github.com/VasiliKubarka) in that issue. I'm just reproducing here for the benefit of others.